# Using pandas for merging csv files

Tags: python-3.x

So I wrote this code to merge csv files in hebrew but I get errors:

```
import pandas as pd, os

writer = pd.ExcelWriter("C:/dir/final.xlsx") # Arbitrary output name
    for csvfilename in os.listdir(main_directory):
        df = pd.read_csv(main_directory + csvfilename, encoding='hebrew')
        df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name = csvfilename[5:])
    writer.save()
```

Comment: *Which* errors do you get? This isn't a [mre], so we are dependent on you to tell us what is wrong.

Comment: pandas.errors.EmptyDataError: No columns to parse from file

Comment: I'm sorry I didn't tell what error I got, it was too long

Answer (score -1):

You can read the csv files using pandas and then merge the dataframes. You can write the output dataframe values to an outfile.csv if you wish.

```
data = pd.read_csv('filename.csv')
data2 = pd.read_csv('filename2.csv')
# if you like to merge one **data** with reference of another field in **data2** 
merged = pd.merge(data, data2, on='Required_field')
merged.to_csv('outfile.csv')
```

You can use pd.concat as well.

Comment: The exception was raised in the read_csv function, so unfortunately it didn't help me

Comment: Hi @eitanpiamenta can you please paste the exception here. May be I can check how to rectify that